# How to add external libraries in Java to sublimetext3

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I downloaded apache commons math and want to be able to use them in sublime text 3. The package I want can't be found in the package control feature, so I wanted to learn how to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add it manually during the compile phase. You would need to add the a class path and refer to it with something like "javac -cp ../math.jar Myclass.java"

Comment: how do I add the class path in sublime?

Comment: I don't add it to sublime I add it to my environment variables, and when I compile on the command line I will add what I have shown above..